Dodged barplot remains stacked, colours displayed as gradient rather than distinct colours
I have a large dataset, containing a categorial (Size) and  a numeric variable(Fraktion) to group the data. The rest are analytical resulst as numeric values. The experiment was conducted in 4 steps, so one column shows these fractions as numeric (1,2,3,4). The other column gives the particle-size (A,B,C) as a categorical variable.



Fraktion
Size
Value_A
Value_B




1
A
4.5
...


2
A
3.0



3
A
2.5



4
A
1.2



1
B
4.4



2
B
2.9



3
B
2.4



4
B
1.3



1
C
4.3



2
C
2.3



3
C
2.3



4
C
1.1




(sorry for the bad formatting, couldn´t figure how to enter a nice simple table)
My goal is to create a dodged barplot, showing on the y-axis the value of interest (e.g. Value_A) and the four fractions for all three particle sizes on the x-axis.
I used this code:
plot<-
  ggplot(df,aes(x=Size, y=Value_A, fill=Fraktion, colour=Fraktion)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge",colour="black")

The resulting plot has still stacked bars, and the colours are displayed in a colour gradient rather than in seperate colours
!
Any ideas why despite the (position="dodge")-Argument the bars are still stacked, and why the colours are shown as gradient?
Many thanks in advance!

Try aes(x=Size, y=Value_A, fill=factor(Fraktion)). By default you get gradient for numeric values, and distinct colors for factors/categorical variables.

Thank you so much Mr.Flick, that solved it! So easy :D
